# Logic analyzer for acquiring EEG signals?

Tags: signal-analysis, analog-to-digital, eeg

Is it possible? I haven't found anything about it on the internet.

I found a logic analyzer here, which is marketed as having the capability to monitor analog signals too:
"One useful feature of your Saleae Logic Analyzer is its ability to measure analog signals (from 0 to 5 V). As such, it can function as an oscilloscope with up to 8 channels (for the Logic 8 and Logic Pro 8) or 16 channels (for the Logic Pro 16)."
(https://support.saleae.com/tutorials/example-projects/how-to-measure-analog-signals)

Could that function as a 16 channel EEG recorder?

As I know, a human EEG electrode would pick up a signal peaking at around 0.1 V... would it be a problem?

Comment: Yes, but that's a meaningless answer.  With a single channel, you couldn't capture meaningful data.  You could use an ADC and monitor its outputs with the logic analyzer, but then you'd just be building a complicated and indirect chart recorder.  Please expand your question to express what you really mean.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to expand the question a little bit now, however I am not really into signal processing, but more into cognitive-psychological experimenting.